# How to prepare grunt to prepare dist folder with app.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, heroku, yeoman

I'm currently playing around with Yeoman Angular Fullstack Generator. That's pretty cool and works as expected. Since it uses grunt, it's possible to run `grunt serve dist` so that it starts the server with my uglified and concatenated files...

BUT:

Last week I found modulus.io (nodejs cloud hosting like heroku) and they were offering a free evaluation phase. Problem: They expect that my project has an app.js so they can start it with `node app.js`.

Question:

Do you guys know how can I use grunt to generate a dist folder just for modulus.io, including all contents of the already generated dist folder (currently just frontend code) + all needed server-side javascripts + an appropriate app.js (that uses express and the contents from the dist folders) and the package.json file?

Any help would be appreciated. :) I think a similar task must exist somewhere since you might have this problem on any other cloud hosting platform. Unfortunately I couldn't find a proper solution

Regards,

Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, modulus.io is just looking for an entry-point into the application. It can be called whatever you like, so long as in your `package.json` file you have a line that tells it what to launch, ie. `"main": "dist/app.js"`.

See: https://modulus.io/codex/projects/app-guidelines for more info.

The full stack generator that you are using should have generated all this for you however...?

EDIT: Running a simple `grunt` command will create a `\dist` directory that is ready to be uploaded.

Comment: Hi, running `grunt` alone does in fact create a `/dist` folder, but it only creates the `package.json` file... not the nodejs file (e.g. app.js) itself. :(

Comment: Ahhh... I found it. It's in the `server` directory! :) Thx very much! :)

Comment: No problem, glad you got there in the end! :D